# Calculate the sum of two positive or negative integers

Tags: python

I am learning python by trying to solve question as follows.

Calculate the sum of two integers a and b, but you are not allowed to use the operator + and -.

Example:
Given a = 1 and b = 2, return 3.

The following solution that I have came up works with positive integers but it does not work if a= -1 and b =1.

I wonder how do you handle negative values.

```
class Solution(object):
def getSum(self, a, b):
    """
    :type a: int
    :type b: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    while b != 0:
        carry = a&b
        a= a^b
        b= carry<<1
    return a
```

Comment: Can you cheat with what ever python operators, or do you have to use bit operators?

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: If you want to be sassy `sum((a, b))`.

Comment: @hotspring it works with negative numbers as well. It just doesn't work when a & b have opposite signs

Comment: then how could I cope with this situation?

Comment: @miradulo, this link also handles only positive integers. My solution works with positive integers as well.

Comment: A fixed bit length is required for making calculations with signed integers. I'm afraid Python does not guarantee it, but don't know for sure about the internals.

Comment: @hotspring Given your integer is 32 bits, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557464/sum-of-two-integers-without-using-operator-in-python).

Comment: Does the question *require* bit twiddling?  Why not just `return a.__add__(b)` ?

Comment: @abccd Err what makes you think that? Because they are both formatted like Leetcode solutions?

Comment: @hotspring: Could you please clarify if you have to use bit operations? If not, feel free to accept abccd's answer, or, if this is too "sassy" for you, to accept mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of Two Integers without using "+" operator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557464/sum-of-two-integers-without-using-operator-in-python); since it actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your approach, you should check what values do not work, and catch them somehow (e. g., `if a == -1 and b == 1`)

**EDIT:** As *BOi* and *hotspring* pointed out, it only fails when a and b have different signs. You could add a substract function (see the other answer) and use it as `Substract(a, -b)` if a < 0 xor b < 0.

Another possible approach - being slow, but easy - would probably be the following:

1. See if second operand is negative.
2. If it is not (which means, if **b is positive**), increment a and decrement b, until b is zero.
3. If it is (which means, if **b is negative**), decrement a and increment b, until b is zero.

Comment: It does not fail when a and b have different signs. Please look at my answer.

Comment: As hotspring pointed out, it seems to be right anyway. Anyhow, it does not fail in other cases for sure (I hope). This bit operations are nothing one should do in higher-level languages

Comment: @xanoeteux i'm not sure. maybe it didn't help OP or someone decided it didn't help. i dont really know.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is very incomplete. "catch them somehow"? How? What would your implementation look like? Also for the latter approach, how do you intend on incrementing and decrementing without using `+=` or `-=`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. A solution without using built in function such as `sum()`. First you define a function to subtract without the - operator. Then you can use that to solve it. Here you go!:

```
def getSum(a, b):
    negative_number = None
    if a == 0:
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a
    if a < 0 and b < 0:
        pass
    elif a < 0:
        negative_number = a
    elif b < 0:
        negative_number = b
    if (a < 0 and b < 0) and abs(a) == abs(b):
        return int("-%s" % (str(getSum(abs(a), abs(b)))))
    elif abs(a) == abs(b) and (a < 0 or b < 0):
        return 0
    elif negative_number != None:
        x = getSum(abs(a), abs(b))
        if x > 2*abs(negative_number):
            return subtract(getSum(abs(a), abs(b)), 2*abs(negative_number))
        else:
            return subtract(2*abs(negative_number), getSum(abs(a), abs(b)))
    while b != 0:
        carry = a&b
        a = a^b
        b= carry<<1
    return a

def subtract(x, y): #Subtraction function without - operator.
    while (y != 0):
        borrow = (~x) & y
        x = x ^ y
        y = borrow << 1

    return x
print (getSum(-15, 16)) #Substitute -15 and 16 for any values to find the sum
```

Now try whatever posibilities you want. it should work well for most numbers except for a few corner cases which I will attack and I will post the full solution as soon as I have one.

Comment: How about try `getSum(10, -100)`.. still broken.

Comment: @miradulo i don't what to do about that one. Any help?

Comment: You could rewrite `a < 0 or b < 0` as `negative_number != None`. But finally, I assume this answer now to be working. Now wait for the OP…

Comment: Now you're passing two arguments to `abs`.

Comment: @miradulo what do you mean?

Comment: @BOi A parentheses issue :)

Comment: Also now try `getSum(-10, 100)`, doesn't work. Actually now your example case won't work either.

Comment: @miradulo yeah that's why i asked you for help. I dont get why OP cant just use + and -. Making all of our lives harder. :)

Comment: Im going to keep this answer here as we're almost close to getting a full solution. meanwhile, i'll try to figure it out. @hotspring have a look at this. There are still some corner cases to fix but it mostly works. I will let you know when I have a full solution. Feel free to edit or comment if you find a full solution. Thanks

Comment: @BOi This isn't really a code review site though, and this answer doesn't work - I don't see the value in it. Anyhow with Python having an infinite two's complement representation I doubt you're going to get this to work without separating the positive and negative cases entirely.

Comment: @miradulo Done.Found a full solution. It should properly now for real :)

Comment: @hotspring here is the full solution

Comment: @miradulo wow. ur really good at finding errors in code :) I fixed that case as well.

Comment: @BOi Why thank you. Now `getSum(1, -1000)` is 999 ;)

Comment: @miradulo holy moly. This code is going to take a lot of effort to fix ;)