# parseUnsignedInt - what's wrong with this method?

Tags: java, unsigned

my mind going to blow up... What's going on with java?

I see that not only I have misunderstanding so maybe someone will tell me where is the logic of this implementation.

So we have this code

```
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(-5);
    System.out.println(s);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
    System.out.println(i);
```

And of course we will get exception, because parseInt trying to parse 11111111111111111111111111111011 to 4 294 967 291 and of course this is out of range. BUT, why **parseUnsignedInt** parse 11111111111111111111111111111011 to -5 ??? Where is the logic? This is Unsigned! First of all I'm expecting that this method will return me unsigned Int ( I know that java doesn't have it ), but ok, let's try to imagine that **parseUnsignedInt** it's not about return value, it's about parameters, but again! If this is unsigned so 11111111111111111111111111111011 should be positive value, not **-5**. Please tell me, what's the point? Because for me it looks like Sun\Oracle is trolling developers.

P.S. I just tried to repeat this experiment in C#

```
        string s = Convert.ToString(-5, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(s,2);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

and no problem. i = -5! As I expected. And also Convert.ToUInt32(s,2) will return me 4 294 967 291

UPDATE: Guys, maybe you don't understand me. I'm not looking for solution. I just confused that java core method contains "unsigned" word but has nothing to do with it. When you use **parseUnsignedInt** you expect that method will return you unsigned number. but -5 != unsigned number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary presentation of negative integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315782/binary-presentation-of-negative-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Integer.toBinaryString converts to two's complement format.
use Integer.toString( -5, 2) if you want got get the binary digits.  but it will be a leaded by '-' not '1'.